# Common Controller for ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to call a common controller everytime ng-view is changed? i.e i want a common controller to be called everytime a new $route is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have specified custom controllers for your different routes, then there's no way that I  know of that you can also specify a common controller that always gets invoked, unless you use some kind of inheritance and always call a method in the base controller.

An alternative approach is to subscribe to the events the route service broadcasts.

Example:

```
function MyController($rootScope, [...]) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (current, previous) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

You have a list of available events and their parameters [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route#Events).

I believe you also can add properties, methods etc. to `$rootScope` which you can use in bindings in your views thanks to how Angular's binding mechanism works. If it doesn't find it on the current scope, it checks its parent etc. up to the root scope.